# use navigator clipboard to store image/png from canvas blob

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, chart.js, angular12

I tried to store canvas blob into navigator clipboard

```
graphicDiv.addEventListener(
      'click',
      (event) => {
        const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('canvas');
        canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
          if (blob) {
            let data = [new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })];

            navigator.clipboard.write(data).then(
              function () {},
              function (err) {}
            );
          }
        });
      },
      false
    );
```

it seems something is wrong since TS gives me errors as follow

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: Blob; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, ClipboardItemData>'.
  'string' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'Blob' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<ClipboardItemDataType>
```

```
error TS2339: Property 'write' does not exist on type 'Clipboard'.

102            let data = [new ClipboardItem({ [blob.type]: blob })];
                                      ~~~~~
```

is there any one familier with how to store canvas **chartjs** chart into the clipboard?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#typedefdef-clipboarditemdata
6.4.2. Writing to the clipboard

These data types must be placed on the clipboard with a corresponding
native type description if added to a DataTransfer object during copy and
cut events.

```
 text/plain

 text/uri-list

 text/csv

 text/html

 image/svg+xml

 application/xml, text/xml

 application/json
```

Comment: Can you expand on `with a corresponding native type description` and provide an example?